# C# - Copy files - from folder to folder - only new files (like sync) - an idea

Tags: c#, file, copy, directory, synchronization

can someone help me with a code in C#, what I need is a program that copy files from foder to folder, like a sync, but without deleting them if in the first folder they are deleted. For example first folder is "source" folder the second is "destination" folder.

My "source" folder for example is my photo sync folder from iCloud. There're photos there and my program copy all files from it to destination folder. But if I delete photo or photos from source to not sync it destination folder. If there's a new photo in source to be copied to dest folder. The idea is to have all photos from my phone in destionation folder. I can't have them in source folder cuz if I delete photo from my phone it's synced with the folder and then deleted from source folder. And I don't wanna copy every time new photos from folder to folder. Just a little program that checks if there a new photos that are not in destination folder and to copy them to it.

Ohhh well a lot of words for this simple thing, but hope to help understand what I want. And the second thing is how the program will check if there is a change in the source folder? Anyway, hope someone to have an idea and maybe example with code would be nice. Thanks.

---

Latest source:

**DELETED**

Comment: Post code, be specific, tell us where in your code you experience a problem, explain what you have tried and read these topis before posting questions: stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Also please edit your question to not be one block of text as it'll put off most people from even reading it.

Comment: I only read the first line (I stopped at "what I need is a program").. stackoverflow isn't a website to ask for freelancers, it is for help with existing programming problems.

Comment: Well I need an idea, it's easy to find or weite a code that copy all files from folder to folder....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the updated code. I have done some small correction by changing the event handler from "Changed" to "Created",check the file exists and also applied error handling to check that the file is available before you try to access it.

```
  private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        watch();
        syncAllFilesFirstTime();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void syncAllFilesFirstTime()
    {
        //Get list of files from sourcepath
        string[] arrFiles = Directory.GetFiles(strSourcePath);

        foreach (string sourceFiles in arrFiles)
        {
            //get filename
            string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(sourceFiles);
            string strDesFilePath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", strDesPath, strFileName);
            //check whether the destination path contatins the same file
            if (!File.Exists(strDesFilePath))
                File.Copy(sourceFiles, strDesFilePath, true);
        }
    }

    private static void syncUpdatedFiles(string strSourceFile)
    {
        //get filename
        string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(strSourceFile);
        string strDesFilePath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", strDesPath, strFileName);
        var val = File.Exists(strDesFilePath);
        //check whether the destination path contatins the same file
        if (!File.Exists(strDesFilePath))
        {
            for (; ;)
            {
                if (IsFileLocked(strSourceFile))
                {
                    File.Copy(strSourceFile, strDesFilePath, true);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private static void watch()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = strSourcePath;
        //watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.Filter = "*.*";
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
        syncUpdatedFiles(e.FullPath);
    }

    public static bool IsFileLocked(string strSourcePath)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = new FileStream(strSourcePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, that's better than the hate I've received. Thanks! Do you have an Idea how to catch if there are new files in the source folder? I have an idea with a timer, but to check every second, don't think it's a good idea. Maybe an event on folder change or something? Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: @beBoss Thanks!! Are you creating an app using Mobile or Windows/Website application

Comment: Look at FileSystemWatcher: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Windows desktop app, on C# :)

Comment: Check out the link which is provide by Neil Verreynne

Comment: So, now i have to create a watcher 

`private void watch()
{
  FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
  watcher.Path = path;
  watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
  watcher.Filter = "*.*";
  watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
  watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}`

and then to call your code in the two events "Changed", "Created", right?

Comment: Yup you have to, make sure that you have initialized this watch() method.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the first post, can you check the exception which the vs gives me, thanks!

Comment: Well I've tryed it and seems to works the way I need, will do more tests later, but now I think this is the solution.

Comment: Well a new edit again :D It works at the start, but after an hour/two or something else the program freeze and can't stop it, and some photos/files aren't synced. Clicking stop button freeze the program. What could be wrong again?

Comment: May be it's because of infinite for loop plz have break point and debug it. Otherwise put some logic like re-try 10times... based on your need

Comment: Debugging isn't my  strong side, but a retry logic sounds good. May be a method that calls stop and start again?

Comment: Okay. You may also use while do until it reach the limit, no need new method

Comment: Oh I have no idea how to implement this thing in my code. I've tried with while do, but can't stop while do loop. And where actually is the right place to write it? And the idea is on every 10min for example to stop the watcher and to start it again, right? A hint or help be appreciated :)

Comment: It's better for you to create windows service..background service. check out this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/naresh.avari/develop-and-install-a-windows-service-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Well, I will try, but service sounds hard for my programing abilities :D

Comment: Well, one more question, I made it as a service and works perfect, but will it have the same problem as the desktop app, I mean the infinity loop pronlem? And if the answer is yes, hot to restart the service, without batch files, something in the code? Or any other way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the file in the destination (backup) already exists.

Use this version of `File.Copy(sourceFileName As String, destFileName As String, overwrite As Boolean)` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx) with the parameter overwrite to **true** and it will be ok. The version that you use has overwrite to false so it throws an exception when the file already exists.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But sometimes throw an exception 

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\beBoss\Desktop\Source\1.png' because it is being used by another process."


well the file isn't open, so maybe something with my code isn't okay? It copy all files but sometimes give me this exception.

Comment: @beBoss You can find the process that has an handle on your file with Process Explorer from Sysinternals [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Comment: @beBoss It's because of our event handler is trying to access the file before the current process gets complsted.